# jQuery toggle full class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I am trying to toggle the class name of an icon in jQuery.

I'm using the font-awesome library, and it only replaces the initial "fa" in my class, here is my jsfiddle

```
$('[name="caret"]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fa fa-caret-up fa-1x');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XrGU8/159/)

Comment: What you have in your jsfiddle is no where similiar to the code you have posted here

Comment: Also what version of jquery are you using (not too sure if `ToggleClass` api would change often) because according to the docs: `ToggleClass accepts: One or more class names (separated by spaces) to be toggled for each element in the matched set.` [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: Sorry, I was editing a previous jsfiddle and I didn't realize the URL hadn't been changing when I hit run, updated.

Comment: @Arthur, that fiddle is working, it is toggling the classes you have provided it?

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to achieve?

Comment: Is it changing the caret to a square or caret-up for you guys? I would like it to change to caret-up but I am getting an empty square (improper class)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it is not changing to `fa-caret-up` because you are also toggling the class `fa`, which is mandatory for font awesome library to realize that it is an icon.

So just do

```
        $('[name="caret"]').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
        });
```

This will remove the `fa-caret-down` class and will add `fa-caret-up` class.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/XrGU8/160/)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I am *very* new to jQuery and was completely stumped. Thanks

Comment: I can't accept for a couple minutes, I haven't forgotten!

Answer (score 1):

Instead just use this:

```
$(this).toggleClass('fa-caret-up');
```

As in the css you can see the order of the classes. The one is last it just overrides the upper one in the order. So toggling a class `fa-caret-up` to an existing one is enough.

You can see the sample below:

```js
$('[name="caret"]').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-caret-up');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.accordion {
  border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
}

.accordion dt {
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-top: 0px solid #c1c1c1;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion dt span {
  float: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.accordion dt .accordion_icon {
  float: right;
}

.accordion dt.active {
  background: #DBDBDB;
}

.accordion_content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-right: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="75px"><i name="caret" class="fa fa-caret-down fa-1x"></i></th>
      <th width="125px"><i name="caret" class="fa fa-caret-down fa-1x"></i></th>
      <th width="550px"><i name="caret" class="fa fa-caret-down fa-1x"></i></th>
      <th width="100px"><i name="caret" class="fa fa-caret-down fa-1x"></i></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "input[name='caret']" ).click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('fa-caret-up')) {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass('fa fa-caret-down');
  } else {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass('fa fa-caret-up fa-1x');
  }
});
```